# A Template-Tag Perplexity

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I've managed to condense my confusion to the following code:

```
template<typename T>
class BTI {
public:
    char func(char);
};

template<int i>
class Tag {};

template<int i> unsigned char
BTI<Tag<i> >::func(char c) {
    return c;
}
```

This is intended to:

1. Declare the template class `BTI`,
2. Declare a templatized tag class `Tag`, and
3. Provide a template-specialized implementation of `func`, when `BTI`'s template parameter is a `Tag<i>`.

When I run this through `g++ -fsyntax-only` (Using g++ 4.1.2.), I get:

```
test.cc:11: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘class BTI<Tag<i> >’
test.cc:2: error: declaration of ‘class BTI<Tag<i> >’
test.cc:11: error: template definition of non-template ‘unsigned char BTI<Tag<i> >::func(char)’
```

I'm not even sure what to try at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: but BTI in not templatized, that is it never uses T. also the specialization returns an unsigned char, not a char??

Comment: func isn't a template function, so you can't specialize it. I think you may have to specialize the whole class, or maybe make func a free standing helper (template) function. I will have a play...

Comment: Added to what @BoBTFish said, even if `func` were a function template, you could *still* not specialise it because you attempt a *partial* specialisation and C++ only supports full specialisations for function templates (as oppposed to class templates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're attempting what I think you're trying to attempt, then you need to specialize the `BTI` entirely, not just the one function; like this:

```
 template<typename T>
 class BTI {
 public:
     unsigned char func(char);
 };

 template<int i>
 class Tag {};

 template<int i>
 class BTI<Tag<i> > {
 public:
     unsigned char func(char);
 };

 template<typename T> unsigned char
 BTI<T>::func(char c) {
     return 'X';
 }

 template<int i> unsigned char
 BTI<Tag<i> >::func(char c) {
     return c;
 }

 int main() {
    BTI<int> x;
    BTI<Tag<0> > y;
    std::cout << x.func('a') << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.func('a') << std::endl;
 }
```

This will first print `'X'` (the general case), then `'a'` (the specialized case).

Comment: Yes. This, plus the above comments by BoBTFish and Konrad Rudolph are excellent; thanks!

Comment: In particular, your version will *not* work without the definition of `class BTI<Tag<i> >`, but *will* work without the definition of  `class BTI<Tag<i> >` if `func`'s is fully-specialized. (like so:
`template<> unsigned char BTI<Tag<0> >::func(char c) {return c;}`
)
Which is exactly as the comment by @Konrad would predict. :)